# Itunes file sharing and Adding open in function support for apps in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I use iTunes file sharing and add the Open IN function support to my app and use them?
My file formats are mp3.

Comment: What did you try for now ? Did you read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your app’s Info.plist file, and set the value of the key to `YES`.
2. Put whatever files you want to share in your app’s Documents directory.
3. When the device is plugged into the user’s computer, iTunes displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected device.
4. The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.

To allow listing your app has a candidate to open mp3 add the mp3 file extension to the URL Types section in your project's Info plist property area.

Comment: Ok but how can I access that file?

Comment: Basically when you enable file sharing your app's Documents directory is visible in iTunes when you connect the device. You can drag and drop files to or from that folder and access it within the app.

Comment: I don't understand how to add MP3 extension to URl Types section.

Comment: Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html for more info on how to register your app to handle files of specify type.